# Wine in OS X: Issues with paths that include spanish special characters

Tags: macos, macports, encoding, wine

I have installed Wine via MacPorts on OS X El Capitan so I have a standard wine setup. I am having the following issue:

My default language in OS X in English but I am Spanish therefore some of my folders and files have characters like "á,é,í,ó,ú,ñ,¿". For some reason Wine cannot display Spanish characters properly. For example, I have installed AIMP 4, and everything works perfectly except Wine cannot display Spanish characters in their names. See the images below for more information.

(First image shows how it should like, second image shows how wine encodes this path names.)

[image: Folders in Finder with the right Spanish characters]

[image: Folders in the wine Explorer, showing how wine is using a different encoding]

Does someone know how to fix this? I have already tried changing the path setting "LC_MESSAGES=es_ES.UTF-8 wine path_to_exe" but it does not change anything.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That looks like the font does not contain the required characters

Comment: @Mark I don't think it is just this. If a software like AIMP (an audio player) can't properly read the paths of a playlist (path containing spanish special characters) it means that the issue should be more than just the font it is using. It is readying a path from the playlist (which is just a text file) and when searching for the path it can't find it because the wine assign different charas to this paths... What is more strange is that this is the default wine installation, and the problem would affect to any software running over wine for Spanish people and I guess a lot other non-english.

Comment: How do you know that AIMP can't read the paths (you say it works) - but just can't show them

Comment: @Mark AIMP works, but every file on the playlist that has a path with one of this characters won't work (AIMP will mark it as file not found), I would have to go the the playlist file, replace the spanish chars like á or ¿ by this weird symbols of the second picture, and then AIMP recongnizes them and plays them. So I just meant that AIMP 4 works very well with wine (except this issue, which is not related with AIMP but with how wine works in my system). Any other ideas? thanks in advance

Comment: So AIMP is not working then it does not play the file - I don't understand what you are asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many other locale variables besides `LC_MESSAGES`.
Try doing the same for `LANG` and also for `LC_ALL`.

Comment: LANG=es_ES.UTF-8 wine .wine/drive_c/Program\ Files/AIMP/AIMP.exe did the trick! I actually read somewhere that LANG was deprecated and not used anymore in recent wine versions, so that's why I didn't even try :S. Anyway, yours is the bounty :)

Comment: Awesome!  Glad I could help!